# Benefit of stubbing controller specs

Tags: model-view-controller, testing

Why it is convention to stub database calls in controller specs? I am mostly looking into insight on why (or why not) it is good to stub out database calls in the controller. My opinion is that stubbing in some cases if it is a simple query (ie. find by id) then it is okay, but when you get into more complex queries it is useful. I could also argue the point that you shouldn't have complex queries in your controller and that any logic like that should be done in the model.

Let me know what you think or how you feel about this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The stubbing is particularly useful for simulating integration points in order to write pure unit tests without external dependencies.
This means that its usefulness is note really based on the complexity of the queries, but rather as a way to abstract out dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I like to place my database calls separately. I place the database functions in a separate class regardless of how simple or complex the query is.

1. **It gives me a sophisticated design and a centralised logic.**
2. **I can easily reuse the functions in any controller.**

Basically, I simulate stored procedures. I have been practicing this on my last and current project and I have a positive feedback about it.

Answer (score 0):

DB calls have no place in controllers. Presentation layer (controllers, views, templates, etc) shouldn't even be aware that there exists any type of storage (whether SQL database, remote REST API or some magical text fiule). The DB interaction should happen in model layer, where it is performed by separate group of instances - something similar to [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

Basically, your MVC is broken.